# Yjw to connect to Weblogic admin server?

Tags: weblogic, wlst

I build and run a docker image with Weblogic 12.2.1.4 and now trying to write a script to create users and groups. I am trying to connect to the administration server to create groups and users. I run `wlst.sh` and execute command `connect('admin','AdminAdmin1','t3://localhost:9002')` but i get an exception -

```
WLSTException: Error occurred while performing connect : Error getting the initial context. There is no server running at t3://localhost:9002 : Failed to initialize JNDI context, tried 2 time or times totally, the interval of each time is 0ms.
[Login failed for an unknown reason: P]
```

admin & AdminAdmin1 - it's username & password from domain.properties file.
How to connect to admin server?

Comment: Are you sure that the 9002 port is not a ssl port ?
If so your URL should be t3s://localhost:9002

Answer (score 0):

You are using the default WLS administration Port 9002. So far so good, but the administration port is always running with SSL. So use `t3s://localhost:9002` and not `t3://localhost:9002`

Comment: WLSTException: Error occurred while performing connect : Cannot connect via t3s or https. If using demo certs, verify that the -Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore=DemoTrust system property is set. : Failed to initialize JNDI context, tried 2 time or times totally, the interval of each time is 0ms.